# Show Heading when Div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to display one of two headings depending on whether some DOM elements are available / visible on the page. For some reason, it's not working... Here's the [live demo](http://goodfruitguide.co.uk/best-fruit-available-now) so far.

I've got the following code:

```
$('h3.list_heading').css('display', 'none');
$('h3#error').css('display', 'none');
    if ( $('div.availableNowListing').filter(':visible').length == 0) {
        $('h3#error').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('h3.list_heading').css('display', 'block');
    }
```

At the moment, no matter what I select I only ever get one heading displayed...

**EDIT**
Just to explain what should happen:
When clicking on the store to sort by, it should only display entries that's associated with that store. If there's no fruit associated with that store, the heading:

*Our Suggestion of the Best Available in xxxxx this Week*

should change to

*Bad Luck! It seems we could't find any good fruit at xxxxx store this week*

**EDIT 2**
Tried using the following code, but nomatter which store I select to sort by, I just get the error message even if the div's I'm looking for are present...

```
$('h3.list_heading').hide();
$('h3#error').hide();
if ( $('div.availableNowListing:visible').length) {
    $('h3#error').show();
} else {
    $('h3.list_heading').show();
}
```

Comment: I saw the page, what are you reffering to can you please tell?

Comment: Just added some clarification :)

Comment: Oh, you mean to say that if the user changes the selection of the combo box to a value and if there are no sub-values under the selected one, then the heading enclosing the combo box should change?

Comment: I clicked the morrisons item. The message is showing well

Comment: Yep, the message works well once... But if you select another store to filter by, say Asda, the same error message displays despite there being fruit available. It's like a one-hit wonder :)

Comment: Asda is a good example, it finds Apple and Avocado but still says 'bad luck'.  @Tiny Giant Studios: is there any chance you can recreate this on jsfiddle so it's more readily editable? Also, don't prefix ID selectors with a tag, use simply `#error` instead of `h3#error`.

Comment: I tried clicking in the following sequence, morrisions->all->asda->morrisons->all-asda, everything works fine.

Comment: can you please upload some code demo on JSFIDDLE and provide the link?

Comment: Will do the jsfiddle thingamabob now :). And I'll do make the ID selectors in jquery momentarily...

Comment: Just uploaded a decent version to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beUJx/ - It's actually the first time I'm using jsfiddle, so lemme know if it doesn't work :)

Comment: Your problem isn't the function itself, it's just not being called at the right time. The value of `$('div.availableNowListing:visible').length` [is always 4](http://i.imgur.com/Bmun5.png), no matter which store you choose.See my answer below for possibly a better time to call your function.

Comment: EDIT2 won't work as `$('div.availableNowListing:visible').length` will evaluate to `true` if it's greater than zero.  You want that the other way around (not that any of it works anyway, of course!) ;)

Comment: @Marcel - hindsight being 20/20 :) Thanks for checking this out and helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these lines in your `switch`

```
$('div.availableNowListing').not(':first').find('div.available_now_entry').fadeOut('fast');
check_heading();
```

to this instead, shifting the function call as a callback for `fadeOut()`.

```
$('div.availableNowListing').not(':first').find('div.available_now_entry').fadeOut('fast',  check_heading);
```

Comment: This looks like a good suggestion - there are too many elements getting selected by the `:visible` selector at the time it runs.

Comment: Man, where we you 6 hours ago? :) - Thanks, it seems to have worked perfectly!

Comment: @TinyGiantStudios: If a method ever has a callback, it's with good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, but try changing the code to:

```
$('h3.list_heading').hide();
$('h3#error').hide();

if ($('div.availableNowListing:visible').length) {
    $('h3#error').show();
} else {
    $('h3.list_heading').show();
}
```

Comment: Nuts, just tried it - but now I only get the error message no matter which store I select. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's tied to the drop-down menu. If I select a store, and there's no fruit in, then it should display the error message. Now this does happen, but only once. If I select another option from the dropdown menu, the original error sticks and doesn't get replaced by the h3.list_heading... Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onscreen_sort (get_store) {
  var check = false;
  $('div.availableNowListing').each( function() {
      // Reset Display
      var correct = $(this).children('.' + get_store).not(':first-child')
      var incorrect = $(this).children(':not(.' + get_store + ') ').not(':first-child')

      if(correct.length > 0) record = true;

      correct.find(":hidden").fadeIn('fast');  //only hide which is not correct ->less dom overlow
      incorrect.find(":visible").fadeOut('fast'); //any only show which is correct but hidden
  });
  check_heading(check)
}

function check_heading(boo) {
  $('h3#error').hide();
  $('h3.list_heading').hide();    

  if (boo) {
      $('h3.list_heading').show();
  } else {
      $('h3#error').show();
  }
}

switch ( store_selected ) {
  case "all" : 
      var class_match = "in_all"
      onscreen_sort(class_match);
      $('span.store_change').text( ' All Stores' );
      $('div.availableNowListing').not(':first').find('div.available_now_entry').fadeOut('fast');
      //check_heading();  //no more needed!
      break;

  case "asda" : 
     ...
     ...
     ...
```

I hope this works. God luck!

Comment: Jeepers, I would never have thought of that! I'm gonna do some error checking with the solution above (so far so good) - but if I pick up anything, I'm definitely giving your solution a try. Thank you so much for looking into this...